# How to read multiple data sets from one .csv file in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a temp recorder that (daily) reads multiple sensors and saves the data to a single .csv with a whole bunch of header information before each set of date/time and temperature. the file looks something like this:

```
"readerinfo","onlylistedonce"
"downloadinfo",YYYY/MM/DD 00:00:00
"timezone",-8
"headerstuff","headersuff"

"sensor1","sensorstuff"
"serial#","0000001"
"about15lines","ofthisstuff"
"header1","header2"
datetime,temp
datetime,temp
datetime,temp

"sensor2","sensorstuff"
"serial#","0000002"
"about15lines","ofthisstuff"
"header1","header2"
datetime,temp
datetime,temp
datetime,temp
"downloadcomplete"
```

My aim is to pull out the date/time and temp data for each sensor and save it as a new file so that I can run some basic stats(hi/lo/avg temp)on it. (It would be beautiful if I could somehow identify which sensor the data came from based on a serial number listed in the header info, but that's less important than separating out the data into sets) The lengths of the date/time lists change from sensor to sensor based on how long they've been recording and the number of sensors changes daily also. Even if I could just split the sensor data, header info and all, into however many files there are sensors, that would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly a CSV file in the traditional sense. I imagine you already know this, given your description of the file contents.

If the lines with `datetime,temp` **truly** do not have any double quotes in them, per your example data, then the following script should work. This script is self-containing, since it declares the example data in-line.

**IMPORTANT**: You will need to modify the line containing the declaration of the `$SensorList` variable. You will have to populate this variable with the names of the sensors, or you can parameterize the script to accept an array of sensor names.

**UPDATE**: I changed the script to be parameterized.

### Results

The results of the script are as follows:

1. sensor1.csv (with corresponding data)
2. sensor2.csv (with corresponding data)
3. Some green text will be written to the PowerShell host, indicating which sensor is currently detected

[image: ScreenshotFiles]

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot2]

### Script

The contents of the script should appear as follows. Save the script file to a folder, such as `c:\test\test.ps1`, and then execute it.

```
# Declare text as a PowerShell here-string
$Text = @"
"readerinfo","onlylistedonce"
"downloadinfo",YYYY/MM/DD 00:00:00
"timezone",-8
"headerstuff","headersuff"

"sensor1","sensorstuff"
"serial#","0000001"
"about15lines","ofthisstuff"
"header1","header2"
datetime,tempfromsensor1
datetime,tempfromsensor1
datetime,tempfromsensor1

"sensor2","sensorstuff"
"serial#","0000002"
"about15lines","ofthisstuff"
"header1","header2"
datetime,tempfromsensor2
datetime,tempfromsensor2
datetime,tempfromsensor2
"downloadcomplete"
"@.Split("`n");

# Declare the list of sensor names
$SensorList = @('sensor1', 'sensor2');
$CurrentSensor = $null;

# WARNING: Clean up all CSV files in the same directory as the script
Remove-Item -Path $PSScriptRoot\*.csv;

# Iterate over each line in the text file
foreach ($Line in $Text) {
    #region Line matches double quote
    if ($Line -match '"') {
        # Parse the property/value pairs (where double quotes are present)
        if ($Line -match '"(.*?)",("(?<value>.*)"|(?<value>.*))') {
            $Entry = [PSCustomObject]@{
                Property = $matches[1];
                Value = $matches['value'];
            };
            if ($matches[1] -in $SensorList) {
                $CurrentSensor = $matches[1];
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green -Object ('Current sensor is: {0}' -f $CurrentSensor);
            }
        }        
    }
    #endregion Line matches double quote
    #region Line does not match double quote
    else {
        # Parse the datetime/temp pairs
        if ($Line -match '(.*?),(.*)') {
            $Entry = [PSCustomObject]@{
                DateTime = $matches[1];
                Temp = $matches[2];
            };
            # Write the sensor's datetime/temp to its file
            Add-Content -Path ('{0}\{1}.csv' -f $PSScriptRoot, $CurrentSensor) -Value $Line;
        }
    }
    #endregion Line does not match double quote
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the data sample you provided, the output of this script would as follows:

C:\sensoroutput_20140204.csv

```
sensor1,datetime,temp
sensor1,datetime,temp
sensor1,datetime,temp
sensor2,datetime,temp
sensor2,datetime,temp
sensor2,datetime,temp
```

I believe this is what you are looking for. The assumption here is the new line characters. The `get-content` line is reading the data and breaking it into "sets" by using 2 new line characters as the delimiter to split on. I chose to use the environment's (Windows) new line character. Your source file may have different new line characters. You can use Notepad++ to see which characters they are e.g. \r\n, \n, etc.

```
$newline = [Environment]::NewLine
$srcfile = "C:\sensordata.log"
$dstpath = 'C:\sensoroutput_{0}.csv' -f (get-date -f 'yyyyMMdd')

# Reads file as a single string with out-string
# then splits with a delimiter of two new line chars
$datasets = get-content $srcfile -delimiter ($newline * 2)

foreach ($ds in $datasets) {
  $lines = ($ds -split $newline)                   # Split dataset into lines
  $setname = $lines[0] -replace '\"(\w+).*', '$1'  # Get the set or sensor name
  $lines | % {
    if ($_ -and $_ -notmatch '"') {                # No empty lines and no lines with quotes
      $data = ($setname, ',', $_ -join '')         # Concats set name, datetime, and temp
      Out-File -filepath $dstpath -inputObject $data -encoding 'ascii' -append
    }
  }
}
```